# How to get those rows where all the values are same against unique id

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID       State      City       Pincode      Code      Date
U-1      AAB        CCV        141414       121       2018-04-04 18:08:17
U-1      AAB        CCV        141414       121       2018-04-04 18:08:17
U-2      BTB        ERV        150454       145       2018-05-05 19:11:25
U-2      BTB        ERV        150454       145       2018-05-05 19:11:25
U-3      FFT        ERT        160707       150       2018-05-22 21:37:45
U-4      FFT        RTT        160707       150       2018-05-28 14:23:48
```

I want to fetch only those rows where all the values are same in the particular unique ID.

Output:

```
ID       State      City       Pincode      Code      Date
U-1      AAB        CCV        141414       121       2018-04-04 18:08:17
U-1      AAB        CCV        141414       121       2018-04-04 18:08:17
U-2      BTB        ERV        150454       145       2018-05-05 19:11:25
U-2      BTB        ERV        150454       145       2018-05-05 19:11:25
```

Comment: Is your question for MySQL or Redshift? Please only include one database tag in your question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the duplicate rows and join the result to the original table.

```
select * from table a
join ( select id,state,city,pincode,code,date
       from table 
       group by id,state,city,pincode,code,date 
       having count(*) > 1 ) b
on a.id = b.id
and a.state = b.state
and a.city = b.city
and a.pincode = b.pincode
and a.code = b.code
and a.date=b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT count(*) AS c FROM table 
    WHERE c > 1 
    GROUP BY ID
)
```

Get all rows where count of the records with this ID is greater than 2 (at least two rows with this id)